# Issue when compile python in c file

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, compilation

so I was trying to compile a very simple cpp file with a with a simple use of PyRun_SimpleString

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Py_SetProgramName((const wchar_t *)argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    std::cout << Py_GetVersion() << std::endl;
    PyRun_SimpleString("print("Hello")\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is in the compilation, if I use the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS given by python3.config

```
CFLAGS = -I/Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/include/python3.8 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64
LDFLAGS = -L/Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-darwin -lpython3.8 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

The programme doesn't compile and show this error

```
ld: in /Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-darwin//libpython3.8.a(pythonrun.o), could not parse object file /Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-darwin//libpython3.8.a(pythonrun.o): 'Unknown attribute kind (61) (Producer: 'LLVM10.0.0' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1103.0.32.62_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 11.0.3, (clang-1103.0.32.62)' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [asciiArt] Error 1
make: *** [re] Error 2
```

And if i use CFLAGS and LDFLAGS that I found to work

```
CFLAGS = -I/Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/include/python3.8
LDFLAGS = -ldl -framework Python
```

It compile but the python version use by the programme is Python 2.7.16 and I need to use Python 3 !

I try a lot of things to fix the error and look on internet but without success.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: You never actually link to the Python library in your first case, you only tell the linker where to look.

Comment: Your LDFLAGS needs a `-lpython3.8m ` to actually link the library

Comment: with the modification now it shows

ld: in /Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-darwin//libpython3.8.a(pythonrun.o), could not parse object file /Users/*myname*/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-darwin//libpython3.8.a(pythonrun.o): 'Unknown attribute kind (61) (Producer: 'LLVM10.0.0' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1103.0.32.62_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 11.0.3, (clang-1103.0.32.62)' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


make[1]: *** [asciiArt] Error 1

make: *** [re] Error 2

Comment: `"print("Hello")\n"` No, this doesn't really compile.